# Bootstrap 4 Popover inline styling issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the color of the Bootstrap 4 popover title dynamically using the inline HTML style attribute. Unfortunately the plugin is removing them without any logic... as you can see in the following example:

```js
$('#test').click(function(e){
     $(this).popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: 'body', 
        html: true,  
        title: '<span style="color:red">my title</span>',                                                 
        content: '<span style="color:blue">my content</span>',        
    });   
  
  $(this).popover('show');
 });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="test" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Any idea to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Popover has a `whiteList` option, which contains allowed attributes and tags.

The default value of `whiteList` is [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer).

You can add new values to this default `whiteList` like this:

```
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.whiteList['*'].push('style')
```

Then your inline style should work.

Comment: That's the correct answer. Is a bit too late because I already used another Popover but this should work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Where do I have to put this line?

Answer (score 3):

Update the template to insert you own classes then you can easily control using external CSS:

```js
$('#test').click(function(e){
     $(this).popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: 'body', 
        html: true,  
        title: 'my title', 
        content: 'my content',
        template:'<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header red"></h3><div class="popover-body blue" ></div></div>'
    });   
  
  $(this).popover('show');
 });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.red {
  color:red;
}
.blue {
 color:blue;
}
</style>
<button id="test" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

If you don't know the colors used you can dynamically append the `style` element using jQuery.

```js
$('#test').click(function(e){
     var r1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200);
     var r2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*200);
     var c1 = '#00ff00';
     var c2 = '#ffff00';

     $(this).popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: 'body', 
        html: true,  
        title: 'my title', 
        content: 'my content',
        template:'<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header c'+r1+'"></h3><div class="popover-body c'+r2+'" ></div></div>'
    });   
    $('head').append('<style>.c'+r1+' {color:'+c1+';}.popover-body.c'+r2+' {color:'+c2+';}</style>')
  
  $(this).popover('show');
 });
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="test" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: The popover can be of any color that the user chooses. These are infinite. I can't create a class for each color.

Bad response.

Comment: @DanA.S. check the update, you can add the style dynamically using JS and you can put any color you want

Answer (score 2):

Inline styles are automatically deleted by Bootstrap when it comes to popovers. You'll have to create CSS classes to control them like shown below:

```js
$('#test').click(function(e){
     $(this).popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: 'body', 
        html: true,  
        title: '<span class="redPopover">my title</strong>',                                                 
        content: '<span class="bluePopover">my content</span>',        
    });   
  
  $(this).popover('show');
 });
```

```css
.redPopover{
  color: red;
}
.bluePopover{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="test" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Is there any reason for Bootstrap to do this? They turn the popover into something unusable and force me to look for an alternative.

Comment: @DanA.S. I think it's a design choice. There's no clear reason for why they do it.